# Force seamless loop of jQuery ticker script

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using a jQuery ticker-type script. It has a particular issue, though, in that it doesn't loop seamlessly. It cycles the images and then there is a blank space, and then it cycles again. I would like it to cycle in an endless loop with the same distance between the last image and the first.

I've tried CSS-wise with playing with the margins of the child div, etc., but can't get the script to remove the blank space between cycles. Is there any way to get this script to loop in a seamless fashion?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vzqyue1/) of the script with some demo html.

The script itself:

```
function marquee(a, b) {
    var width = b.width();
    var start_pos = a.width();
    var end_pos = -width;

    function scroll() {
        if (b.position().left <= -width) {
            b.css('left', start_pos);
            scroll();
        }
        else {
            time = (parseInt(b.position().left, 10) - end_pos) *
                (10000 / (start_pos - end_pos)); // Increase or decrease speed by changing value 10000
            b.animate({
                'left': -width
            }, time, 'linear', function() {
                scroll();
            });
        }
    }

    b.css({
        'width': width,
        'left': start_pos
    });
    scroll(a, b);

    b.mouseenter(function() {     // Remove these lines
        b.stop();                 //
        b.clearQueue();           // if you don't want
    });                           //
    b.mouseleave(function() {     // marquee to pause
        scroll(a, b);             //
    });                           // on mouse over

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    marquee($('#band'), $('#band-content'));  //Enter name of container element & marquee element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this plugin as alternate: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/58n3r6c4/)

Style:

```
#band {
    position:relative;
    width:1022px;
    height:120px;
    line-height:120px;
    overflow:hidden;
  background:blue;
}
#band-content {
    position:absolute;
    height:120px;
    line-height:120px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#band-content img {
    position:relative;
    top:-1px;
    height:68px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:68px;
}

.a {   
  overflow: hidden;  
}

.a1{
  list-style: none;
}

.a li {    
  float: left;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="band" class="a">
                <ul id="band-content" class="a1">
                    <li><img src=""></li>
                    <li><img src=""></li>
                    <li><img src=""></li>
                    <li><img src=""></li>
                    <li><img src=""></li>
                    <li><img src=""></li>
                    <li><img src=""></li>
                    <li><img src=""></li>
                    <li><img src=""></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#band").scrollForever();
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to only scroll once though and then stops, as far as I can tell, in the JSFiddle. Also, not sure where exactly to add that .scrollForever function. I tried adding it at the bottom of the existing jQuery script to test, and it was overridden it seems.

Comment: You can check its demo [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-For-Infinite-Any-Content-Scroller-scrollForever.html)